# How can I correct DNS in resolved.conf - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dns, configuration

I had file system errors in sda1 (orphaned INODES).  After fixing that problem several configuration files are not functioning.  Probably the most critical is the DNS lookup function.  resolved.conf shows:

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

I can edit the file in mousepad, but cannot save it.  I've also tried terminal commands edit, sudo edit, nano and sudo nano.  None of these provides a useable copy of resolved.conf.  Ubuntu documentation says to fix my problem by editing this file.

How can I edit this file and then save a working version?

Answer (score 0):

Run fsck once again
`sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda1` than reboot the system. To disable fsck on boot run `sudo tune2fs -c 0 /dev/sda1`